# How to control gzip and sed process

Tags: sed, gzip, task-management

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10, Linux 5.3.0-40-lowlatency (x86_64).

Since a while, one of my PCs, is working a lot with some process (apps) I've never programmed to work: "GZIP" and "SED" (and there are other apps eating CPU time when gzip and sed are working, too).

These "invisible" jobs are slowing down somethings in the PC, like audio/video playing, or the mouse movements, because they can eat up 25% of the  CPU time (I can see it in the Task Manager GUI).

These undesirable jobs can run up for 15 minutes, or more, two or three times a day!

How can I control and/or full disable all those undesirable jobs?

Comment: gzip and sed are not launching by themselves. Take a look into cron jobs to see if there's a job which calls them. See https://linuxacademy.com/guide/21076-crontab-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you so much for this data! It seems to be really useful!

Comment: Could it be automatic updates (security or other updates of program packages)?

Comment: I seems to me it is something related with clamav, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apps [gzip](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gzip.1.html) and [sed](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sed.1.html) are not launching by themselves.

The most likely cause to launch them is a script called by [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto), by a job in [crontab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man5/crontab.5.html). Take a look into the cron jobs in that system to see if there's a job which calls them. Some useful guidance is shown at http://linuxacademy.com/guide/21076-crontab-in-ubuntu